# async.detect without errors to Promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, promise

I have some code using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library that currently uses `callback(err, result)` style callbacks, but needs to work with promises. I have an array of data items that need to be passed to a promise-returning function. I want any one object in the array whose promise completes successfully (i.e. without errors). With async, I'd do something like:

```
var foo = function(dataIn, callback) {
    async.detect(dataIn, function(datum, cb) {
        bar(datum, function(err, result) {
            if(err) cb(false);
            else cb(true);
        });
    }, callback);
};
```

Is there a (good) way to do this with browser-based promises?

Comment: If possible, getting the `result` value for the `datum` that succeeded would be good as well.

Comment: Are you looking for `detect` or for `detectSeries`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no such function for native promises (fully-featured libraries like Bluebird do have helper functions such as [`Promise.any`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html)), so you'd have to implement it yourself:

```
function firstFulfilled(promises) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        for (var i=0; i<promises.length; i++)
            Promise.resolve(promises[i]).then(resolve, function() {
                if (--i == 0)
                    reject(new Error("no promise was fulfilled"));
            });
        if (i==0)
            reject(new Error("no promises given"));
    });
}

var foo = function(dataIn, callback) {
    firstFulfilled(dataIn.map(bar)).catch(function(err) {
        return undefined; // not sure whether you want this, but async.detect does it
    }).then(callback);
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to execute the asynchronous functions sequentially, then it might be a bit simpler:

```
function firstFulfilled(data, callback) {
    return data.reduce(function(acc, datum) {
        return acc.catch(function() {
            return callback(datum);
        });
    }, Promise.reject(new Error("no promises given")));
}
```